# What does Watchdog !@Sync error indicate?

Tags: android

Android logcat gives me an error of `E/Watchdog(  747): !@Sync 12552`. The 747 I would guess is the PID and 12552 seems to be a counter as it is incremented with each occurrence.

What does Watchdog !@Sync error indicate?

Comment: have you found out? This is still the first hit on google for this error, but I couldn't get an explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering [this](http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.com/2010/11/androids-watchdog.html) (pre-KitKat) and [this](http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.com/2014/05/androids-watchdog-kitkat.html) (KitKat) website:

> Android framework's watchdog is meant to deal with cases when any of
>   the following locks is held for more than a minute or when
>   ServerThread is busy.
>
> - `ActivityManagerService.this`
> - `PowerManagerService.mLocks`
> - `WindowManagerService.mWindowMap`
> - `WindowManagerService.mKeyguardTokenWatcher`
> - `WindowManagerService.mKeyWaiter`

So, the error is related to that.

For KitKat it could also be a package manager not responding for 10 minutes or another custom implementation, see KitKat link above.